# Changing Value Formatting in Rails Admin's Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I have a column for my `User` model that displays `phone_numbers` lifted directly from the database. I want my Rails Admin to display these number formatted.

For example:

`` `Current` => `What I want`
1234567890 => (123) 456-7890 ``

This is currently what I have in my `rails_admin.rb` file:

```
  config.model User do
    list do
      field :id
      field :full_name
      field :email
      field :phone_number
    end
```

I tried implementing the virtual field from the wiki (https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields) but that didn't work

```
# From users.rb - User Model
  def phone_number_formatted
    #method to format number
  end

  # From rails_admin.rb
  config.model User do
    list do
      field :id
      field :full_name
      field :email
      field :phone_number_formatted, :phone_number
    end
```

Any suggestions? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are a some gems that provide phone number formatting functionality, you could try them, https://github.com/daddyz/phonelib is one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the rails admin formatting logic contained you can do this

```
  config.model User do
    list do
      field :id
      field :full_name
      field :email
      field :phone_number do
        formatted_value do
          value.split('-') # Or whatever you want to do
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: perfect! exactly what I needed

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to all fields of a specific type? Say, I want all boolean fields to appear as "Yes" or "No".

Comment: Booleans by default are checkboxes do you want them to be two radio button with the Yes and No labels right?

Answer (score 3):

Check wiki again, and you will see `Just define them as methods on your model, then configure a field of the same name.`

so, just define a `phone_number_formatted` methods in your user model

and use `field :phone_number_formatted` in rails_admin.rb